# Need to update banner in angular without making frequent calls

Tags: java, angularjs

I have situation where on every notification set by the admin i need to display it in the header part of the page as a banner for all the logged on users. 
Currently i am using $interval, but it is making a server call in every 5 minutes set in the $interval, which is increasing total hit on the server.
i need an efficient way to call only when there is a new entry in the database and stop hitting the server if the banner time is expired.

Answer (score 2):

To do that you would need to reverse your logic - you need push notifications from the server to your app.

I would look into Websockets - [this is a nice Angular module](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket)  that could help you with that implementation

Comment: Stan, i found websocket is not supported by IE10 and some older browsers, also do i need to config websocket at server side? is there any other way possible as i have the event, when admin sets the notification.

Comment: That's true, older browsers don't support websockets so you'll need a Flash fallback. You could give [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) a try - there's a free version and if your needs get bigger, they have paid optioins. They use websockets and have two fallback mechanisms in case that's not available.